# PM2 installation issue

Tags: pm2

i'm using a mac m1 and i'm trying to install PM2, but it's not installing.

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. -> to solve about this problem, i tried to install higher uuid version. but its not work (same warning message displayed.)

so i ignored that warning and tried to check the version of PM2, and it said like that.
-> zsh: permission denied: pm2

-MacBookPro ~ % sudo npm install uuid@7.0.3 -g

added 1 package in 269ms -MacBookPro ~ % sudo npm install pm2@latest -g npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic. See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

changed 185 packages in 1s

12 packages are looking for funding run npm fund for details -MacBookPro ~ % pm2 --version zsh: permission denied: pm2